# How to activate the button in android only when required?

Tags: android, button, widget

I have several text fields in my application. I want to save the inputs of those textfields. So the condition is, 
when all the text fields are full,then only the save button should get activated. until then it should be disabled. how can i do this? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourEditText.getText().toString()))`

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @ M D M a beginner, please let me know more. before writing the above statement should i make th button setEnabled false?

Comment: @Android-Learner you can make an "else" statement, that will setEnabled false. However, setEnabled doesn't hide the button itself. I suggest you to use setVisibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:visibility` in Button

Let say I have 2 TextView and 1 Button

In XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

In Java:

```
Button saveBtn = (Butotn) findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
EditText field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(field1.getText().toString() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(field2.getText().toString())) btn.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
else btn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,

you should use TextChangeListener with you EditText this will listen text you enter in EditText and when all EditText have some values in it you should use button.setEnabled(true/false) method to make this button clickable and non-clickable.